# Solve the following problem.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinations

We have a 4 x 4 matrix which can be filled with only 0 and 1. In how many different ways can it be filled? In how many ways can it be filled in symmetry with the first diagonal? The answers are $2^{16}$ and $2^{10}$ but why?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "in symmetry with the 1st diagonal"

Comment: @GCab: OP means symmetric with respect to the diagonal from the upper left to lower right.  See JMoravitz's answer for further details.

Comment: @BrianTung, ok, thanks, so $A=A^T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication principle of counting.

Let our matrix be $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\\i&j&k&l\\m&n&o&p\end{bmatrix}$

- Pick the value of $a$ (*two options, either $0$ or $1$*)
- Pick the value of $b$ (*two options, either $0$ or $1$*)
- $\vdots$
- Pick the value of $p$ (*two options, either $0$ or $1$*)

Multiplying the number of options available at each step we get $2^{16}$ different arrangements for the first part of the problem.

For the second part of the problem, since we must have symmetry our matrix looks like

$\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d\\b&e&f&g\\c&f&h&i\\d&g&i&j\end{bmatrix}$

- Pick the value of $a$
- Pick the value of $b$
- $\vdots$
- Pick the value of $j$

Multiplying the number of options available at each step (*and making sure we count how many steps there are correctly*) we get $2^{10}$ arrangements.

---

A paraphrasing of the multiplication principle of counting, also sometimes referred to as [the rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) is:

> To count the number of outcomes of a scenario, if you can describe *every* outcome *uniquely* via a sequence of steps such that the number of options available for a step does not depend on the specific choices made at previous steps (*though the available options themselves may vary*), the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options available at each step.

Comment: I'm unsure why this received a downvote.  If the downvoter cares to explain the reason, I may have a chance to improve the post.  Otherwise, since the post includes all mathematically correct and factual information, an easy to implement approach, and the correct answers I see nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can put, repetitions allowed, $\;m\;$ objects in $\;n\;$ holes in $\;m^n\;$ different ways, and thus there are $\;2^{4\cdot4}=2^{16}\;$ differents square matrices of order four with only ones and zeros.

What you seem next to want is to count **symmetric matrices**, meaning: matrices which remain the same if you switch rows and columns. But such a matrix is completely determined by the elements in its main diagonal *and above it*, totalling $\;4+3+2+1=10\;$ spots to fill, and thus there $\;2^{10}\;$ such matrices

Comment: $m$ (*distinct*) objects in $n$ (*distinct*) holes... in $m^n$ different ways? Check that.  It should be $n^m$ instead